# Using sudo in python script

Tags: python, ping, lan

I am working on a project which pings LAN devices and writes the avg_time taken by the ping in a MySQL db.

```
# Python script to update contents of MySQL database

import MySQLdb
import subprocess
import re

#Connecting to MySQL database
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","tempLocal","thunderbolt","dbavgspeed")
#initializing cursor
cur = db.cursor()

error = "Request"

while 1:
    # 0.1 is the interval between pings and 4 is the number of times ping operation is performed and -t 1 sets the timeout to 1 sec 
    command1 = ['ping','-n','-i','0.1','-t','1','-c','400','192.168.1.1']
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(command1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #text is the string which stores the output from the terminal
    text1 = p1.stdout.read()


    if error in text1:
        status1 = 0
        cur.execute("""UPDATE tbavgspeed SET status = %s WHERE id = %s""",(status1,1))
        db.commit()
    else:
        status1 = 1

        find11 = re.search("stddev(.+?)ms", text1)
        allValues1 = find11.group(1)
        find12 = re.search("/(.+?)/", allValues1)
        avgTime1 = find12.group(1)

        cur.execute("""UPDATE tbavgspeed SET avg_time = %s, status = %s WHERE id = %s""",(avgTime1,status1,1))
        db.commit()

#terminates the connection
db.close()
```

- The script is working fine with simple ping command, but how do I use flood ping (ping -f) through a python script which requires sudo
- Is there a better way to calculate current data transfer rate for a router

Comment: Try running your python script in superuser mode: `sudo python ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could run your Python script with `sudo`. For example:

```
import os
os.system('ping -f google.com')
```

Without `sudo`:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ping -f google.com')
ping: -f flag: Operation not permitted
19712
```

With `sudo`:

```
$ sudo python
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ping -f google.com')
PING google.com (172.217.6.78): 56 data bytes
.^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
409 packets transmitted, 408 packets received, 0.2% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.334/3.645/9.459/0.362 ms
0
```